# Automatically Resizing with BorderLayout in Java

Tags: java, jframe, resize, netbeans-8, border-layout

This is my jFrame Form with BorderLayout where buttons will be placed in Navigation Bar Panel and jDesktopPane will be placed in Content Panel. The DesktopPane with CardLayout will be displaying different sizes of jPanel Form. I want Content Panel(including whole form) resize based on the different sizes of jPanel Form displayed. Is it possible to do this? If not then I've tried resizing the panel and even the whole form with codes, but it's not working.

[image: System Design]

I've trying playing with these few codes, but it's not working.

```
Main_Menu form = new Main_Menu();
form.pack();
form.setSize(900, 548);
form.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 548));
form.validate();
```

Comment: The layout managers will do this automatically; avoid using `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` and let the layout mangers do there jobs

Comment: The description of your problem doesn't make a lot of sense, consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

So, based on the limited information available, I wrote a quick test which seems to work just fine

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
                JDesktopPane pane = new JDesktopPane();
                Navigator navigator = new Navigator(pane, layout);
                pane.setLayout(layout);
                pane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

                frame.add(new TopPane(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(new NavigationPane(navigator), BorderLayout.WEST);


                for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                    pane.add(new ContentPane(index), Integer.toString(index));
                }

                JLabel initial = new JLabel("All your content belong to us");
                initial.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
                pane.add(initial, "initial");

                layout.show(pane, "initial");

                frame.add(pane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Navigator {
        private JComponent parent;
        private CardLayout layout;

        public Navigator(JComponent parent, CardLayout layout) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.layout = layout;
        }

        public void show(String name) {
            layout.show(parent, name);
        }
    }

    public class TopPane extends JPanel {

        public TopPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            JLabel title = new JLabel("Top Panel");
            title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            add(title);
        }

    }

    public class NavigationPane extends JPanel {

        private Navigator navigator;

        public NavigationPane(Navigator navigator) {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
            setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                JButton btn = new JButton("Test " + index);
                btn.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(index));
                add(btn, gbc);

                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String name = e.getActionCommand();
                        navigator.show(name);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public class ContentPane extends JPanel {
        public ContentPane(int value) {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
            setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
            add(new JLabel("Hello from " + Integer.toString(value)));
        }
    }
}
```

Avoid `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize`, you're overriding the work which the components and the layout managers do in order to provide dynamic sizing hints

If this fails to solve your issue, then consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `pack();` not `form.pack();`. Or `setLayout` or use `CardLayout`

Comment: *"Try to use pack(); not form.pack();"* - What if the class isn't a window based class?  `form.pack()`, based on the available code, would seem to be the correct approach